# How do I choose a registered dependent type at runtime using Unity IoC?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am new to Unity and I'm having trouble resolving the correct object.

I have a class CustomerManager that takes, as a dependency IDataAccess.

CustomerManager

```
public class CustomerManager
{
    private IDataAccess dataAccess;

    public CustomerManager(IDataAccess dataAccess)
    {
        this.dataAccess = dataAccess;
    }

    public Customer GetCustomer(int id)
    {
        return this.dataAccess.GetCustomer(id);
    }

    public void SaveCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        this.dataAccess.SaveCustomer(customer);
    }
}
```

IDataAccess

```
public interface IDataAccess
{
    void SaveCustomer(Customer customer);
    Customer GetCustomer(int id);
}
```

I have 2 classes that implement IDataAccess called SQLServerDataAccess and MongoDataAccess.

What I am trying to do is register both the classes that implement IDataAccess and then use Resolve to create an instance of CustomerManager.

Here is my register:

```
UnityIoC.Instance.RegisterType<IDataAccess,SQLServerDataAccess>("SQL");
UnityIoC.Instance.RegisterType<IDataAccess,MongoDataAccess>("Mongo");
```

When I try to resolve an instance of the IDataAccess classes directly it works fine.

```
IDataAccess dataAccess = UnityIoC.Instance.Resolve<IDataAccess>("Mongo");
```

However, when I try to resolve CustomerManager I get an exception.

I am doing this:

```
CustomerManager manager = UnityIoC.Instance.Resolve<CustomerManager>();
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "UnityIoCExample.CustomerManager", name = "(none)".

Exception occurred while: while resolving.

Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, UnityIoCExample.IDataAccess, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

-----------------------------------------------

At the time of the exception, the container was:
Resolving UnityIoCExample.CustomerManager,(none)

Resolving parameter "dataAccess" of constructor UnityIoCExample.CustomerManager(UnityIoCExample.IDataAccess dataAccess)

Resolving UnityIoCExample.IDataAccess,(none)
```

It's clear to me that the exception is caused by Unity not knowing what registered type of IDataAccess to use as the dependency to CustomerManager but I can't figure out how to specify that. I'm I doing it mostly correct and just missing one piece or am I way off?

My only thought is to use ParameterOverride when resolving CustomerManager and to resolve IDataAccess inside of CustomerManager using that parameter.

Modified CustomerManager constructor:

```
public CustomerManager(string dbType)
{
    this.dataAccess = UnityIoC.Instance.Resolve<IDataAccess>(dbType);
}
```

To resolve CustomerManager

```
CustomerManager manager = UnityIoC.Instance.Resolve<CustomerManager>(new ParameterOverride("dbType", "Mongo"));
```

I'm not sure if that is really the best practice.

Comment: Sample of how you want your resulting code to look like may help. I.e. if you want Unity to "magically" pick class you want you need to register that interface with empty name and somehow pick one of the `Resolve<IDataAccess>("Mongo")` calls there.

Comment: I basically want this:

UnityIoC.Instance.RegisterType<IDataAccess,SQLServerDataAccess>("SQL");
UnityIoC.Instance.RegisterType<IDataAccess,MongoDataAccess>("Mongo");

CustomerManager manager = UnityIoC.Instance.Resolve<CustomerManager>();

Obviously I need to tell the Resolve<CustomerManager>() which IDataAccess to use to resolve CustomerManager. I am missing that piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an InjectionContructor in the scenario that you have described.

```
UnityIoC.Instance.RegisterType<IDataAccess,SQLServerDataAccess>("SQL");
UnityIoC.Instance.RegisterType<IDataAccess,MongoDataAccess>("Mongo");

UnityIoC.Instance.RegisterType<CustomerManager,CustomerManager>("Mongo", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IDataAccess>("Mongo")));

UnityIoC.Instance.RegisterType<CustomerManager,CustomerManager>("SQL", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IDataAccess>("SQL")));

CustomerManager manager = UnityIoC.Instance.Resolve<CustomerManager>();
```

To keep this class tidy its some times better to extract it out into a DIConfig Class of its own. several of these InjectionConstructors will be reusable and extracting in a class will help with that.

Comment: That did it. I was trying something similar to that but just couldn't figure it out. Thanks so much.

Yes, if this was a real project I'd have things organized better. This is just in the main of a console application. I'm just learning Unity now.